# Changing text from another activity

Tags: android, settext

How to dynamically change the content of a TextView from another part of the screen?

I have a TabActivity class that draws a RelativeLayout that contains a TextView followed by a  with several tabs. Within each tab is a separate Intent. From one of the tab intents, I would like to change the text (via .setText) of the TextView from the parent TabActvity.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) :

You can create a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) containing [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) of your data object (`LiveData<String>` in case you want to change only text).

When you will change your live data object from one `Activity` or `Fragment` all other Activities and Fragments observing for this live data object will get notified.

[Official API doc has complete example with description](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html).

Comment: Be wary that this will change that `TextView` for every instance of that class on the stack.

Comment: "Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)" - Not a better solution anymore. You will get this warning in Android Studio while making it static. Any better solution?

Comment: Gives me a NullPointerException. 
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @AneesU Agree, updated outdated and incorrect answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Make a public method in your TabActivity that sets the TextView's text, then call `getParent()` from the child activity, cast it to your TabActivity class, then call that public method.

Comment: Wow, this is a great idea, keeping everything in the TabActivity class. Will definitely try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing a handler for the parent Tab which does the job. Pass the text in a message object from each of your respective tabs. To be safe, make changes within the handler inside a runOnUI block

Comment: Thanks... I actually thought of that and tried it but probably implemented it incorrectly. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In a case of changing text from asynctask file, you need to implement an interface with a listener. Example:

**AsynctaskFile:**

```
OnReadyListener onReadyListener;

public class ABCAsynctaskFile{

   ...

   onReadyListener.onReady();

}

public interface OnReadyListener{

void onReady();

}


public void setOnReadyListener(OnReadyListener onReadyListener){

this.onReadyListener = onReadyListener;

}
```

**ActivityFile:**

```
public class ABC extends AppCompactActivity implements ABCAsynctaskFile.OnReadyListener{
   ..

   ABCAsynctaskFile aBCAsynctaskFileObj = new ABCAsynctaskFile(context);

   aBCAsynctaskFile.setOnReadyListener(ABC.this)

}

@Override

public void onReady(){

   // Your wished changed in edit text.

}
```

This structure will help you to prevent null pointer exception.