# Android Change TextView text from another class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a `TextView` in `MainActivity`, I would like to change the `TextView` text within another class.

How can I access `TextView` in `MainActivity` from another class?

I tried the following

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

textView.setText("Text");

But the app crashes when calling `setText()`

Comment: You can check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605588/changing-text-from-another-activity?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996479/how-to-update-a-textview-of-an-activity-from-another-class

Answer (score 9):

You have to use **runOnUiThread(new Runnable()...**

See following:

```
import android.content.Context;

private class AnotherClass {
        protected MainActivity context;

        public AnotherClass(Context context){
            this.context = (MainActivity) context;
        }

        public void updateTV(final String str1){
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    context.textView.setText(str1);    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the text of the TextView a possible way would be to edit the text in a common data model that is shared by your classes. If `onResume` from the activity is called later it can read the new value from the model and update the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a handler to update the content of that Activity. This is only one way, there is multiple ways to do this.

The entire purpose of a handle is to have some background process/thread passing information into the UI thread.