# How to change value of TextView from another Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-cardview

In the application I'm trying to develop I have a layout `featured_workshop_layout` with CardViews with buttons. Each button with displays same layout but with different data based on each cards. I tried the below method but keep getting FATAL Exception.

check the button1 here (featured_workshop_layout)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- android:background="#E1F5FE">
A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:text="Android 2.0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentTextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titleTextView1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titleTextView1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="Venue: SJT 311 \n Time: 29/10/2015 5-7pm \n Note: Bring charged laptop"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:onClick="showRegister"
            android:tag="SITEAndroid 2.0"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="#FFA000" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:text="IEEE-SPS Core Committee Selections"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contentTextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titleTextView2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titleTextView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="Venue: TT 724 \n Time: 30/10/2015 6-7.30pm"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:onClick="showRegister"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="#FFA000" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:text="IQ VIT DEXTER"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="Venue: MB210\n Time: 31/10/2015 5.30pm\nContact: 9484356876"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:onClick="showRegister"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="#FFA000" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void showRegister(View view)
{   String site = "SITE";
    String taginfo =  view.getTag().toString();
    System.out.println(taginfo);
    //check tag content
    if(taginfo.contains(site)) {
        System.out.println("tag has keyword site");
        RegistrationForm.schoolName.setText(site);
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            RegistrationForm.class));

}
```

RegistrationForm.java

```
public class RegistrationForm extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText rno;
EditText name;
TextView displayTemp;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
public static TextView schoolName;
public static TextView workshopName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration_form);
    rno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_rno);
    name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    schoolName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.schoolName);
    workshopName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.workshopName);
    displayTemp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
    displayText();

}
```

I have declared `TextView` as `public` in `RegistrationForm.java`, where i want to display the details. When accessing it from `MainActivity` to change the value, I get the following exception.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.intodarkness.vitworkshop, PID: 9770
>                                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4025)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                           at com.example.intodarkness.vitworkshop.MainActivity.showRegister(MainActivity.java:52)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
>                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
Instead of trying to access the required fields from MainActicity, I accessed the required details from CardView in MainActivity and did rest of the operations in Registration form where I was able to access TextViews of registration_form.

I used System.out.println() statements to find the order of execution where I found out Activity was called only after setText statements which is why I got the nullException error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is here:

```
if(taginfo.contains(site)) {
    System.out.println("tag has keyword site");
    RegistrationForm.schoolName.setText(site);
}

startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
        RegistrationForm.class));
```

I would recommend your to send the param from one activity to another using `Intent.putExtra()` instead of `static` variable.

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510771/2219237 you can find an example how to do it.

Comment: But why is this method not working?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605588/changing-text-from-another-activity

Comment: Have a look at the link you provided "but make sure you initialize that TextView object before you use in other Activity ...". In your case you are trying to set text to `schoolName`, but `RegistrationForm.onCreate()` has not been called yet so the value of `schoolName` is null.

Comment: any suggestion on how to resolve it? I tried writing startActivity(new Intent(this, RegistrationForm.class)); in the very first line of the called function on button click showRegister()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the value of `textview` in `Activity2` Then while going from Activity1 to Activity2 just set the value in `Intent.putExtra()` and start the activity and in `onCreate()` method of `Activity2`, get the intent value by calling `getIntent.getExtras().getString('your_key');`  and change the `textview` value.