# Changing text in class(class A) from another class(class B)

Tags: java, android

I declared String A in Class A and I want to send this String A to Class B(MainActivity that include inputView) for appending to inputview.

I found,

[Changing text from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605588/changing-text-from-another-activity#)

This solution is very simple and easy.

However, android studio warned me that
"Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)".

Any better solution?

Comment: use intent.putextra method to pass string or use sharedPreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Intent is the proper way to achieve data communication over Activities

  > [What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try.

Comment: Happy to hear this.